# Taking the derivative of $f(x) = (x+1)/\sqrt{x^2+1}$

Tags: calculus

This is what I have so far.

$$((x^2+1)^{1/2} - (x+1) * 1/2(x^2+1)^{-1/2} * 2x)/({x^2} + 1)$$

((x^2+1)^(1/2) -(x+1) * x(x^2+1)^(-1/2)) /(x^2+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the quotient and chain rule for the exercise:

$$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Do the derivative straight forward:
Setting: $u:=x+1$ and $v:=\sqrt{x^2+1}$.

So $$u'=1$$ and $$v'=2x\cdot(\frac{1}{2})(1+x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Then $$f'(x)=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-(x+1)(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}})}{x^2+1}$$

It depends on you if you split the fraction into two parts. That's just cosmetics.

If you have further problems, please comment.

Comment: How did you even get that form of $f$... that's obviously wrong

Comment: That's correct. About 3 minutes ago there was an edit to the question. Hence I got the wrong function. I have to edit my answer.

Comment: Oh, that's alright then.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)'=\frac 12(x^2+1)^{-1/2}\color{red}{(x^2+1)'}=\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$
I think you are missing the red part.

Then, you'll get $$f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-(x+1)\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{x^2+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, take the logarithm of $f$

$\ln(f)=\ln(x+1)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2)$

Differentiating both sides,

$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{x}{1+x^2}$

Multiply both sides by $f(x)$, and you're done.